# Generate CSV with UTF-8 to open with excell

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, unicode, utf-8

I am generating some CSV files with utf-8 characteres in ubuntu with python2 which are correctly opened by LibreOffice and google drive. Not successful in Excel Office 2013.

I have tried 'sep=,' but encoding is not correct and also I have tried BOM-ut8 but columns are not correctly opened.

I made some tests with tab separator and encoding UTF-16LE with no results. Following this article:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/CSV+tests+of+encoding+and+column+separator?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com

Comment: Excel will open UTF-8 encoded CSV automatically properly only if BOM exists and the separator used is the one which is set in Windows locale settings. Use the text import wizard to open CSV files having more control. But UTF-16LE encoded CSV having BOM and `sep=,` in first line should work automatically with Excel if that is an option. But tab delimited files UTF-16LE encoded should also work.

Comment: BOM and sept=, in the same first line?

Comment: Yes. First line : `fffe 7300 6500 7000 3d00 2c00 0d00 0a00  ..s.e.p.=.,.....`

Comment: Btw.: BOM is never followed by line feed. Example tab delimited UTF-16LE: `fffe 4e00 6100 6d00 6500 0900 4600 4e00 6100 6d00 6500 0d00 0a00` = `BOM Name tab FName CRLF` as first line if `Name` and `FName` are the column headers.

Comment: I have just achieved just using ';' as delimiter and BOM at the begining of the file. At leas in Office 2013

Comment: See my first comment. Semicolon will work as delimiter for UTF-8 encoded CSV if it is the list separator which is set in Windows locale settings.